# How do you create an empty linked list in C?

Tags: c

I have a C code, in which I am assigned to create an empty list. Although I create one, with Element = 0, it is still considered a list by the program, so it prints 0, when in reality I want it to be printed as NULL. Also, when I print the length of my list, it also comes out as 1, rather the 0 I'd be looking for.

This is my code so far.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    typedef int ElementType;

    struct Node;
    typedef struct Node *PtrToNode;
    typedef PtrToNode List;
    typedef PtrToNode Position;

    List CreateList();
    int IsEmpty(List L);
    int IsLast(List L);
    Position GetNode(List L,int idx);
    void FetalError(const char *msg);
   void PrintList(List L);

    struct Node {
        ElementType Element;
        Position Next;
        Position Previous;
    };

    List CreateList()
    {
        List L;
        L= (List)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        if(L==NULL) FetalError("Out of Memory");
        L->Element = 0;
        L->Next = NULL;
        L->Previous = NULL;
        return L;
    }

Position Insert(ElementType X, List L, Position P)
{
    Position Tmp;
    Tmp=(Position)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if(Tmp==NULL) FetalError("Out of Memory");
    Tmp->Element=X;
    Tmp->Next=P->Next;
    P->Next=Tmp;
    return Tmp;
}

    int IsEmpty(List L){
        return(L->Next==NULL);
    }

    int IsLast(List P){
        return(P->Next==NULL);
    }

       void FetalError(const char *msg)
    {
        printf(msg);
        exit(-1);
    }

    PrintList(List L){

        while(L!= NULL){    
            printf("%d <-> ", L->Element);
            L=L->Next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

        int getCount(List L) 
{ 
    int count = 0;  // Initialize count 
    struct Node* current = L;  // Initialize current 
    while (current != NULL) 
    { 
        count++; 
        current = current->Next; 
    } 
        printf("%d number of elements", count); 
} 
    Position GetNode(List L, int idx){

        int i = 0; 
        while (L != NULL) 
        { 
            if (i == idx) 
                return(L); 
            i=i+1; 
            L= L->Next; 
        } 
        return;  
     } 

    Position Last(List L)
    { 
    return L;
    } 

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
    {
        int i;
        ElementType X;
        List L;
        Position P, P1 , P2;

        srand(0);

        // creat an empty list
        printf("Creating an empty list\n");
        L = CreateList();
        PrintList(L);
        getCount(L);

        // Insert at the beginning
        printf("**(Inserting 5 random numbers at the beginning\n");
        for( i=0 ; i<5 ; i++ ) {
            Insert(rand(),L,L);
            PrintList(L);
        }
        P = GetNode(L,5);
        printf("The Element of 5th Node is %d\n",P->Element);
        getCount(L);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Where in this code are you printing the length?

Comment: It's not on the code, I added code on my own to test for length.

Comment: Depending on the way you implemented your code to do so, it may also have problems. Can you please edit the question and add it in.

Comment: Where is the `insert` function? You don't show us, but there lies the key: let it create the list when called the first time, i.e. when the list is still null.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie My bad, it is included now.

Comment: @finnrayment edited as well.

Comment: The reason why you get 1 and not 0 is because you are allocating memory for `L`, and then setting its children to `NULL`. Then your length function says: "while it's not null, add one and check the children". It is _always_ going to add one because the first one always passes.

Comment: This leads into @DavidRechtman's answer. "You create an object with memory, so it won't be null".

Comment: @finnrayment so what could I do if I wanted to print an empty list?

Comment: Perhaps try restructuring your code so your "head" node points to `NULL`, and your "tail" node also. This is the initial state of your Linked List and thus it is empty. You can feed the head node to your print function which will immediately find that it points to NULL and thus a final length of 0.

Comment: As for printing NULL, do a check on the pointer, and if it equals `NULL`, then `printf("NULL")`. There are alot of ways you can go about correctly implementing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create an object with memory, so it wont be 0\null. 
if you wish to get null object you should return null.

Comment: Do you mean in CreateList function? However, if I return null, then I wouldn't have a header for the next node and I wouldn't have a linked list at all.

Comment: if you create an object it will not be null. you can change your print function to identify it is an "empty list".

Comment: How can I change my print function in such way then?

Comment: add an if statement to check about the first element 0, and no more element. ad for your deceleration of list is an empty list.